# What key to put on the receiver side of Linux message queues?

Tags: c, linux, ipc, message-queue

I have created a message queue and the sender part successfully creates and sends the message to the message queue.

I have used `IPC_PRIVATE` as key in `msgget()` on the sender side.

Now my question is, what key to use in `msgget()` on the receiver side ?

Using `IPC_PRIVATE` on the receiver side as key in `msgget()` does not receive message and fails.

I should also mention that `msgsnd()` in the sender part indicates an error (returns -1), but when printing with `perror()`, the output is `Success` and the message is sent to the message queue successfully and can be seen using ipcs -q command at the terminal. I don't know why this happens.

```
 if(msgsnd(msqid,&msgp,88,IPC_NOWAIT) == 0)
          {
                  perror("\nsend : msgsnd FAIL");
                  msgctl(msqid,IPC_RMID,buf);
                  return 1;
          }
```

Output : 
send : msgsnd FAIL: Success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have to use a common key value between your two independent processes ... using `IPC_PRIVATE` means you are not planning on sharing the queue between two processes unless the secondary process has been forked from the first process.  Because of the forking operation, the child will inherent the queue identifier from the parent process, so using `IPC_PRVATE` in that scenario is okay.  But because using `IPC_PRIVATE` creates a unique key-value for every call its used in, for scenarios where you have two completely independent processes, such as a server/client relationship, you will need to create a common key ... it can either be a "magic number" that you share between all the processes that is already not in-use by another queue, shared memory segment, etc., or you can create a key off a common file in the filesystem by using `ftok()`.

Comment: and why do i get Success as error message in perror() part of msgsnd?

Comment: Why does success come in "send : msgsnd FAIL: Success"

Comment: `SUCCESS` means that you returned a value of `0` which is what you're checking for.  If you wanted to check for a failure, you would have to-do `if(msgsnd(msqid,&msgp,88,IPC_NOWAIT) == -1)`, then check the value of `errno` via `perror()`, at which-point it has been set to a non-zero value.

Comment: thanks jason for pointing out my mistake , i missed that -1 while coding

Answer (score 1):

This question is the reason you should not use the ancient SysV message queues - there's simply no good way to get a key that's unique. Even with `ftok`, collisions are sufficiently likely that you must write code to try to work around them. Pretend you never saw the SysV IPC interfaces and use POSIX message queues instead; see `man mq_open`.